# Equivalent of Ruby nil array in Python

Tags: python, ruby, arrays, list

In Ruby an empty array returns a nil if the first element is accessed:

```
2.1.2 :005 > arr = []
  => [] 
2.1.2 :006 > arr.first
  => nil 
2.1.2 :007 > arr[0]
  => nil
```

I know Python lists are not exactly the same as Ruby arrays, but if you try the equivalent action, you get an error:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

How can I instead of an error get a False or None value?

Ideally I'd like an assignment like this to resolve to None / False if the function call returns nothing, but with an inline check rather than a if block.

```
tp_journal = self.pool.get('account.journal').browse(cr, uid, tp_ids, context=context)[0]
```

Comment: Use a `try ... except` clause.

Comment: `((expression) or [None])[0]` would be a simple hack to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple way to achieve what you want. The list operations raise an error, period.

However you can work around by:

- Accessing something else when the list is empty
- Not using indexing

In the first case you can use the fact that empty lists are false and hence `(expression) or [None]` will evaluate to `[None]` when the `expression` returns an empty list, and hence:

```
((expression) or [None])[0]
```

The alternative is to avoid using indexing but using iteration and `next` to get the first element:

```
next(iter(expression), None)
```

Unfortunately you must explicitly call `iter` to get a list iterator.

To extend these methods to any index you can use slicing instead of simple indexing:

```
((expression)[index:] or [None])[0]
```

Or:

```
next(islice(expression, index, None), None)
# or
next(iter(expression[index:]), None)
```

(where `islice` is `itertools.islice`).

This works because slicing doesn't raise errors for out-of-bounds indexes.

---

Hoever my preferred alternative would be to use a function, if you use that often in your code:

```
def get_with_default(seq, index):
    try:
        return seq[index]
    except LookupError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make use of the short-circuiting nature of the `or` operator.

```
seq = [23,42]
print (seq or [None])[0]
#result: 23

seq = []
print (seq or [None])[0]
#result: None
```

In the above code, `seq or [None]` evaluates to `seq` if `seq` contains any elements, and it evaluates to `[None]` if `seq` is empty. Then [0] accesses the first element of whichever list is returned.

Comment: I think the asker wants this to work for any index that would raise an IndexError, not just for empty lists. At least, that's how it works in Ruby.

Comment: arr.first or arr[0] was what I put. @Max you have more clearly expressed what I was trying to say.